# 1 Wire temperature sensor

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, temperature-sensor

I bought a waterproof temperature sensor from Ebay, I am fairly new to this and not sure what I need or need to do in order to get the sensor to output the current temperature to the serial monitor.

Does anyone have any information on where I can get some information on how to wire this? I have looked at various videos online but they are all for a dallas temp sensor and use the dallas library.

[http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/181393039374?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/181393039374?ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWNX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649)

Comment: "The probe the temperature sensor DS18B20 original chip" from the product page. Look for the DS18b20 library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probe has the Dallas (now Maxim) DS18b20 sensor in it so you're already on the right track. Search for DS18b20 at [arduino.cc](http://www.arduino.cc/). You'll find libraries and lots of forum discussions about using these sensors.
Also see page 6 of the [DS18b20 datasheet](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf); there are two schematics for wiring the device.

I'm using the parasitic mode (Figure 4 on that page) except I eliminated the transistor switch and connected the MCU pin for the strong-pullup directly to the one-wire bus.